# How to map fabric credentials and user IDs provided by the front end apps(such as Angular apps) when calling composer-rest-server?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I read the following sites and understood the concept of wallet.

IBM/BlockchainSmartContractTrading-CompositeJourney:
https://github.com/IBM/BlockchainSmartContractTrading-CompositeJourney

But what we want to do is provide authentication in the front end application (not in the rest server) and map those user IDs to Fabric credentials.
In other words, we would like to specify each Fabric credential which belongs to each user who logged in to the front end app when calling rest API from multiple users concurrently.

Would it possible to implement such scenario leveraging composer-rest-server? 
(I suppose that we can implement such scenario leveraging client SDK...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! The scenario you describe is documented here:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-multiuser.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Let's me clarify my understanding.
My understanding is calling the POST /wallets/{id}/identities/{fk}/setDefault operation set one's blockchain identity as default blockchain identity of the composer-rest-server.
That means if I set Alice's identity as a default by calling the POST /wallets/{id}/identities/{fk}/setDefault operation but what happens if subsequent request comes from Bob? Do I need to call 
the POST /wallets/{id}/identities/{fk}/setDefault operation to change the default blockchain identity of composer-rest-server to Bob's identity?

Comment: No, setDefault is used to set a given user's default blockchain id (hence the {id} in the REST path.